# How to setup User Account Request Form with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am re-factoring a New User Account Request Form we have on our website. The form allows managers to fill out the information we need to create a new User in our system.

Currently there are 4 User Account types:

- Staff, Guest, External Guest, Student

Each account type only share *some* common properties.

The current setup is:

**Model:**

```
public class NewUserRequest
{
    public enum AccountTypeEnum
    {
        Staff,
        Student,
        Guest,
        ExternalGuest
    };

    //All other properties of each account type below
}
```

**View:**

Single View that contains all potential HTML elements for every account type.
Necessary/Unnecessary Elements are shown/hidden with Javascript depending on what account type is selected.

**Pros of Current Setup:**

- Single View to maintain
- Single Form/Model to POST(submit)
- Easy User Experience

**Cons of Current Setup:**

- Wayyyyy to much JavaScript logic to show/hide HTML elements
- Awkward Ordering/layout of HTML Elements
- Easy User Experience

I have considered creating a seperate Model for each AccountType but this means I should create multiple Views. Having multiple Views makes the Form harder to maintain, and means duplicate code.

With all this in mind is there an approach that fixes some of the current Cons, but maintains some of the current Pros?

Comment: You have missed many other cons of the current approach such as inability to validate your model without lots of `[RequiredIf]` type attributes, the need for a major re-write if you added another account type in the future etc. Use separate models and views but make use of a base model and derived models, and partial views to avoid duplication

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for the reply. That's very helpful, and I'll likely implement it how you suggest. I feel like I've often run into similar Delimas for other situations. Maintaining a single view or splitting things up. Is it nearly always better to spectate things? The main issue I see is maintainability, if something common between all models needs to be added, this must be accounted for every view as well. it can be very tricky to maintain in certain situations.

Comment: You should have a `class AccountBase` for the common properties (and derived classes for `StaffAccount` etc) - then it only needs to be added in one place. Similarly you will have a partial view based on `AccountBase` so that its only updated in the view once.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, I'll definitely give this a try!